# If statement within If statement

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, designer-workflow

i do hope you can help. Im very much an amatuer beginner when it comes to SharePoint Designer but am struggling with a list workflow issue.

Im trying to set up a workflow to send emails to the relevant people based upon the 'Request Status' set within the list. Im using 'IF' statements but need to sometimes base the conditions based upon a field value as well as a lookup on another list field.

See code below:

---

```
IF CurrentItem:Request Status equals (3) Submitted 

and CurrentItem:SiteCode:Region equals Europe

Email Regional IT Approvers (Europe)
************************************

IF CurrentItem:Request Status equals (3) Submitted

and CurrentItem:SiteCode:Region equals South America

Email Regional IT Approvers (South America)
```

---

The first issue is with the SiteCode lookup. Site code is a drop down list relating to a master lookup list on the site. In this list are Codes for all global sites, plus the region they all fall in e.g. Europe, South America etc.

The next issue is with the Email side of things. For some reason, i can email an individual user, when the 'Email Person of Group' option is selected but when a Sharepoint group is selected, no users within that group are emailed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i need to get this issue resolved as a matter of urgency. Thanks guys

Luke

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question you can use this logic

```
IF CurrentItem:Request Status equals (3) Submitted
    IF CurrentItem:SiteCode:Region equals South America
        Email Regional IT Approvers (South America)
    IF CurrentItem:SiteCode:Region equals Europe
        Email Regional IT Approvers (Europe)
```

and for more info see [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/br/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/c3b9e735-4c8b-4aff-986e-b1e821bf95aa)

For the second question I suggest you make a second question with that topic so others can find it when the question is answered.

Comment: Thanks buddy, tried it and that code works perfectly. Thanks again for your time and efforts.